# How to create a user input form with WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, forms

I'm completely new to the whole WordPress scene so I kind of don't know the "WordPress way" of doing the desired task:

Create a form where a user would fill in some details (such as name, surname, upload a video or post a youtube iframe link)

Submit it, once it's done - an admin must verify that everything has been filled out correctly and after that the video can be seen on the website.

Should I write a plugin of some sort that would do that or how does it happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) plugin allows you to do exactly what you're looking to do. With it, you can set up a form that creates a post and sets it to be 'Pending Review' in WordPress. [This tutorial](http://gravitywiz.com/use-gravity-forms-to-create-user-submitted-posts/) contains everything you need to know about what you'll need to do.

If you want to create a Custom Post Type (ie. 'User Page') to better separate user submissions, you'll need to employ [this special add-on](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/) (as mentioned in the tutorial above).

Comment: Thank you, but is there a free plugin that would do that as well?

Comment: Not aware of any that specifically do what you're after. And if you do find one, I suspect it wouldn't do exactly what you're after